# Performing a git pull in pure PHP

Tags: php, git, version-control, git-pull

I was wondering if anyone knows of a library or how to perform a get pull request with pure PHP, **without** git being installed on the server.

First of all, is this even possible? I have seen the odd class, but they don't seem to be able to perform pull requests.

I guess an alternative would be bundling some form of stripped down version of git with my script. Would that be possible?

I am really at a loss here so any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to use git without having git?

Comment: Do you want to do a `git pull`, or to do a pull request on some provider like github ? This is not the same.

Comment: @Matt Pretty much. It sounds fairly impossible but I just want to know if anyone else has ever done it. I have been looking at the git folder installed locally, I wonder if you could bundle only the binaries you need in a stripped down version.

Comment: @user576875 It would probably be a pull request from GitHub yes. I want to simulate a `git pull` from a provider such as GitHub.

Comment: http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/29/exporting-your-repository.html

Comment: I don't think it's impossible. The problem is the scope: you'd need to implement at least a portion of git in PHP. That sounds like a lot of work.

Comment: @Matt Indeed it is, there are projects such as [glip](http://fimml.at/glip/doxygen/) but they don't seem to be able to pull.

Comment: @Wolfy, just wondering, what is the usecase for this?

Comment: @Sukumar Being able to pull the latest version of a repository from GitHub (or similar host) to a web server.

Comment: @Wolfy87 You will have to implement git in PHP. There is a git implementation in Java called jgit, maybe you can get some inspiration from there. Alternativly you can simply *copy* the git directory, which will effectively give you a clone of the git repository. Also have a look at [php-git](https://github.com/libgit2/php-git) and [this thing](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5310-PHP-Retrieve-project-files-from-GIT-repositories.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just realised that you can [use SVN to request a repository from GitHub](https://github.com/blog/626-announcing-svn-support).

And [SVN seems supported by PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.svn-checkout.php).

So I will use SVN, it should do the trick.

I hope this has saved someone else the trouble of Googling for hours. Give SVN + GitHub a go.

Comment: this requires svn library to be installed